# Storing a given matrix

Tags: c++

I have to store the matrix

```
1  2  3  4  5
6  7  8  9  10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
```

in a variable called "a".I am given the following code block

```
for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
   for(j=1;j<=5;j++)
   .................
```

which I have to finish.I think there should be some connection between the elements of the matrix,but I can't see any.
EDIT:I must not use any additional variables.

Comment: Hint: they're incrementing by 1.  How many are in each row?

Comment: Where are the numbers coming from? `stdin` or a file? (well, `stdin` is a file, but you get the drift...) And, loops generally go `for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) ...` If there are only 5 elements in your array, you invoke *Undefined Behavior* attempting to store a valued in,, e.g. `a[5][5]`.

Comment: The numbers aren't coming from anywhere.The matrix "a" has initially all the elements equal to 0 and I have to make it store those numbers.I know that loops generally go like that,but this is from an exam in my country where they always start them from 1...(don't ask me why)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin look at the matrix values. It looks like those loop conditions are to make the math easier for the students to calculate values.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Undefined Behaviour is not an issue here,they do not give the acual size of the array so we consider it to be big enough to store all the numbers.

Comment: So the problem is to calculate these numbers using only `i` and `j`?  This is simple math.  You just need to think about it.

Comment: @paddy yes,this is the problem. However,I have no idea what the maths behind it is,this is why I am asking for help here.

Comment: Hint: think of your multiplication tables that you probably learned as a child.  Now look at the last column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array of 5 times 5 integral values; `i` obviously stands for a row index, whereas `j` indicates a column index. The respective value in each cell then is `(i-1)*5 + j`.

But, probably a pitfall introduced by your teacher, be aware that array indizes in c++ start from `0`, not `1`. And that's why I'm giving more hints than usual for a question without any attempt of solving it:

```
int arr[5][5];
for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
   for(j=1;j<=5;j++) {
      val = // enter the expression here
      rowIndex = i-1;
      columnIndex = j-1;
      // insert the one missing statement here :-)
   }
 }
```

Comment: You literally just handed this person the breakthrough that they needed to discover on their own.

Comment: @paddy: right in principle; but from the maturity level of OP it's rather unfair to  let them start with array indizes starting at `1`. That's why.

Comment: @StephanLechner thank you for the solution

Comment: you're welcome. But, as @paddy said, play around and try to figure out the pitfalls and the ratio behind.

Comment: @paddy I really am just an amateur as my nickname says.Even though this is really basic for most of the people here ,I would have never come up with this "simple math".

Comment: @paddy: concerning the `(i-1)*5+j`-thing, you are completely right. I'll take more care the next time.

Comment: "*it's rather unfair to let them start with array indizes starting at 1*" but the OP has said "*this is from an exam in my country where they always start them from 1*" so I don't think there's any trickery happening here with those indexes...